# MySQL replication Tungsten vs. Galera

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, xtradb

Which is better?

In sum of these aspects:

- performance + scalability
- stability
- easy of use + config + maintain

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

The slides from this presentation may be slightly helpful:

http://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2012/sessions/how-evaluate-which-mysql-high-availability-solution-best-suits-you